# Should I include "or" at the beginning of "At least, that was the plan."?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

This is my sentence:

> At least, that was the plan.

Should it be:

> Or, at least, that was the plan.

Or are both sentences grammatically wrong?

**Context (Edited):**

The paragraph preceding this sentence elaborately describes a project as if it really happened. I intend to use this sentence as a "surprise", to show that it was only the plan and not reality

Comment: I don't think your context is sufficient enough to see if the usage of "or" is appropriate.

Comment: SInce it already has a preposed phrase (_at least_) that links it to previous clause, the _Or_ is optional. So is the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the context looks something like this -

I jumped from the cliff, swung through the vines like a well-dressed Tarzan, and landed right on the bad guy's back.

Or at least, that was the plan.

Yeah I'm leaning towards #2...If it were me writing, I'd drop the comma after 'or' though. It looks better :)

Answer (score 0):

Both the sentences are grammatically correct. Though with "or" the sentence sounds better.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Can you be more specific on why the sentence with "or" sounds better?

Comment: Though using "or" adds a redundancy to the sentence, but it is more successful in bringing out the contrast....Hence, it "sounds better".